# @ScriptAssert Path Mapping <forms:errors>

Tags: spring-mvc, validation, hibernate-validator

I have seen that @ScriptAssert is used for duplication validation.  For example,

```java
@ScriptAssert(
  lang = "javascript",
  script = "_this.confirmPassword.equals(_this.password)",
  message = "account.password.mismatch.message")
```

I know that in my jsp file, I can receive this error message globally together with all the other errors as follows:

```xml
<form:errors path="*">
```

However, I want to receive this specific password duplication error message and have it displayed by the password field, however, I do not know by what path name I can retrieve this error?  For example, to receive the Username error by the Username field, the jsp looks like:

```html
<div>
  <spring:message code="newUserRegistration.label.username" />
  <form:input path="username" cssClass="short"
  cssErrorClass="short error" />
</div>  

<form:errors path="username">
    <div><form:errors path="username" htmlEscape="false" /></div>
</form:errors>
```

...but by what name do we retrieve the password error that is checked by @ScriptAssert, especially when there are multiple @ScriptAssert within @ScriptAssert.List?

...which uses username as the path name.  I have checked other forums, etc. to find the path name for @ScriptAssert or the path name for each @ScriptAssert within @ScriptAssert.List, but could not find any solutions.  Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards,
Jamie

Comment: I see form:errors nested in another form:errors. Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1):

Try losing the `path` attribute at all, like this:

```
<form:errors htmlEscape="false" />
```